# Best way to convert ngModel bound input data to number in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an app that sums a lot of data from different fields across several components.  As I learned last night, despite the type being number, all input changes on bound models input them as strings.

Is there an easy way to convert a bound data input to number on change that I can reuse across all my components?   I need to use ngModel to keep the data bound and after a lot of googling I'm not finding applicable solutions.  I know I have to be missing something as this can't be a wide problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Just one example of the use is the following code: (totalKind() is the relevant method)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-herd-list',
  templateUrl: './herd-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./herd-list.component.scss']
})
export class HerdListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('manor') manor: Manor;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  herderIndex(herd: Herd): number {
    return checkResultIndex(herd.checkResult);
  }

  herdYield(herd: Herd): number {
    const result = Math.floor(
      herd.baseYield *
      this.manor.landQuality *
      this.manor.fiefIndex *
      this.manor.weatherIndex *
      checkResultIndex(herd.checkResult)
    );
    return result;
  }

  herdHeadCount(herd: Herd): number {
    return Math.floor(herd.acres * herd.graze);
  }

  herdLabor(herd: Herd): number {
    return this.herdHeadCount(herd) * herd.baseLabor;
  }

  herdKind(herd: Herd): number {
    return this.herdHeadCount(herd) * this.herdYield(herd);
  }

  herdTotal(): {kind: number, labor: number, acres: number} {
    const total = {kind: 0, labor: 0, acres: 0};
    for (const herd of this.manor.livestock) {
      total.kind += this.herdKind(herd);
      total.labor += this.herdLabor(herd);
      total.acres += herd.acres;
    }
    return total;
  }

}
```

The view code below renders the totalKind as a number to start but if I make and value change I get an array of strings back despite that field being typed as number.  I know I need to cast it as a number but want to do so on the ngModel so I can reuse it across all components.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-sm">
  <thead class="thead-light">
  <tr class="row">
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col">Herd</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-1 text-center">RI</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-1 text-center">Yield</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-2 text-center">Acres</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-2 text-center">Labor</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-2 text-right">Kind</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let herd of manor.livestock" class="row">
    <td class="col">{{herd.herdType}}: {{herdHeadCount(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{herderIndex(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{herdYield(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="herd.acres" (ngModelChange)="">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-center">{{herdLabor(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdKind(herd) | number}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col text-right font-weight-bold" colspan="3">Totals:</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdTotal().acres | number}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdTotal().labor | number}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdTotal().kind | number}}d</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There;s no `herdTotal` method. Did you mean `herdTotal`?

Comment: You could cast it in the herdTotal() method: total.acres += +herd.acres;

Comment: have you tried just adding "+" to your assignment or using that in your function to force it to change string to number?  e.g. +herd.acres

Comment: Also input binded with `herd.acres` has type "text" instead of "number".

Comment: What @MateuszWitkowski said it probably the reason it's happening, negating all other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes I meant herdTotal (I refactored before sending).  

I'll try the assignment (I'm assuming you mean in the template? sorry new to angular still).  

The input number problem seems to be documented as unreliable in browsers so I was looking for a way to garentee it in the code.

I'll try those, thanks.